# Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: service, worker

I am passing a React application and I want to convert it to AWP, but the service worker does not connect me

serviceWorker.js:97 Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://frontend-calyaan.vercel.app/') with script ('https://frontend-calyaan.vercel.app/service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').